# Parsing the ELM-327 device data in android app using Bluetooth?

Tags: c, bluetooth, android

I am developing an Android app which is receiving data from ELM-327 OBD device. and parsing it.
                       There are two ways to receive data from ELM-327:-
                   1) using scan tool services.
                   2) using ATMA command.

here is the code for scan tool service.

```
                 public void parser(String msg) 
                 {
                  Parameter parameter= new Parameter();
              String [] strdata=null;
              String init="18 DA F1 10 03 41 1F";
                String erpm="0C";
                        String vspeed="0D";
                      int rpm=0;
                       int speed=0;
                      String init_frm_msg=null;
                      int length=9;
               if(msg!=null)
                       {
                    strdata=msg.split(" ");
                        if(length<8)
                    {
               for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                if(strdata[i]!=null)
                strdata[i]="00";

            }
        }
        init_frm_msg=strdata[0]+strdata[1]+strdata[2]+strdata[3]+strdata[4]+strdata[5];
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), init_frm_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(init.equals(init_frm_msg)){
            if(strdata[6].equals(erpm)){
                rpm = Integer.parseInt(strdata[7]+strdata[8],16);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rpm, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                parameter.setRpm(rpm);
                mGaugeView1.setTargetValue(rpm);
            }
            if(strdata[7].equals(vspeed)){
                speed = Integer.parseInt(strdata[7]+strdata[8],16);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), speed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                parameter.setSpeed(speed);
                mGaugeView2.setTargetValue(rpm);
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg + "   ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

            Here is the code which communicated with the device:-
            protected void onResume() {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if (D)
        Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");
    final String init = "ATI";
    final String init2 = "ATS1";
    final String init3 = "ATH1";
    final String init4 = "ATAL";
    final String cmd_erpm = "010C";
    final String cmd_vspeed = "010D";
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (connected) {
                if (config) {
                    sendMessage(init);
                    sendMessage(init2);
                    sendMessage(init3);
                    sendMessage(init4);
                    config=false;
                }
                sendMessage(cmd_erpm);
                sendMessage(cmd_vspeed);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    };
    runnable.run();


}
```

This is done using send the command and receive the data and parse it.
In this service we need to keep on sending command.

How it can be done using ATMA command?

Means what would be the logic for Parsing that data.

Comment: can you post code sinpet which communicates with ELM327 ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the AT MA command puts the ELM-327 in a bus monitoring mode, so that it listens to all OBD-II related messages on the bus, and then retransmits them. But it does not allow you to send an OBD-II command repeatedly. Moreover, the AT MA command closes the current ECU protocol session to start monitoring. Communications are established again until you request an OBD-II command.

Check more details in the ELM-327 manual:

http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf

Comment: Great! You can Google and you can link to a document. But you did not answer the question. This way you will never gain reputation on Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Once you send the ATMA command you should first get a "Waiting..." response (depends on ELM327 implementation).

Then you will get the frames from the wire via the chosen protocol (use ATSPx)

For full frames send ATH1 first (I see you have that in your sample code).

Parsing the frame data depends on the protocol you are using. Broadly you will have 3 types of parsing to perform on the following protocol types:

1) CAN 11 bit

2) CAN 29 bit

3) ISO (9141 / 14230) and SAE (J1850) serial

Comment: Do you have the original ELM327 adapter? My chinese clone does not send any "Waiting..." message.